# Do android roms with only boot.img file available in fast boot rom don’t have separate recovery.img

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, fastboot, 8.1-oreo, development

I have phone named **Vivo Y83 /(vivo1802)**

I wanted the stock recovery image of my device to port twrp recovery since it’s not officially available for my device.

But after getting hands on my fastboot rom…. There is only boot.img present in rom So my question is is the recovery image is part of boot image in my rom?

And if yes….how would I proceed to build twrp for myself?

Comment: Some ROMs have recovery integrated in their main image.

Comment: Do you mean no separate recovery image? If so then how can I proceed to build custom recovery for myself

Comment: Also my firmware neither have vbmeta image?….strange

Comment: I have just recognized that your device is Mediatek based. Usually for those type of phone fastboot isn't used, instead some proprietary Mediatek flash tool is used. Are you sure you have the correct image? As I wrote on older images the recovery was included in main partition. E.g. on some Nexus devices and on booting the image the recovery was flashed if it was different than the installed one. On newer devices AFAIK there is no longer a separate recovery partition but your phone is not that new.

Comment: I can very much confirm. firmware I have is fully correct image….as I have grabbed it from official site of phone…..and when I received Bootloop while experimenting with patched boot images, I flashed the stock boot.img from that firmware file to recover without data losses. (And yes my phone is mediatek device-I have successfully unlocked it, but due to weird firmware I not being able to experiment on it)

Comment: you should be able to extract recovery.cpio.gz from .ofp with this script https://github.com/bkerler/oppo_ozip_decrypt/blob/fc6aba6/ofp_libextract.py